# Hibernate uniqueResult is null, but it shouldn't

Tags: java, hibernate

Good morning,

I'm trying to the the following thing:

Before updating an object, i want to retrieve a field from the last record to add it in the new row. So this is what i did

```
 int idLuce = Integer.parseInt(msg);
 Illuminazione illuminazione = new Illuminazione();
 session.beginTransaction();
 selectQuery = "SELECT dateTime from Illuminazione i where i.idLuce = :idLuce ORDER BY i.dateTime ASC";
 theQuery = session.createQuery(selectQuery).setProperties(illuminazione).setFirstResult(0)
.setMaxResults(1);
 lastDate = (Date) theQuery.uniqueResult();
 logger.debug("last date time is: "+lastDate);
 illuminazione.setLastDateTime(lastDate);
 illuminazione.setIdLuce(idLuce);
 illuminazione.setIsLit(true);
 Date date = new Date();
 illuminazione.setDateTime(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
 session.save(illuminazione);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
```

everything works as I expected, BUT lastDate is null... I get no errors or exceptions, this is the log of the operation..

```
2015-12-15 10:30:01.157 DEBUG [Thread-2]: HQL: SELECT dateTime from it.besmart.models.Illuminazione i where i.idLuce = :idLuce ORDER BY i.dateTime ASC
2015-12-15 10:30:01.159 DEBUG [Thread-2]: SQL: select illuminazi0_.date_time as col_0_0_ from SMARTPARK.illuminazione illuminazi0_ where illuminazi0_.id_luce=? order by illuminazi0_.date_time ASC
2015-12-15 10:30:01.161 DEBUG [Thread-2]: throwQueryException() : no errors

Hibernate: 
    select
        illuminazi0_.date_time as col_0_0_ 
    from
        SMARTPARK.illuminazione illuminazi0_ 
    where
        illuminazi0_.id_luce=? 
    order by
        illuminazi0_.date_time ASC limit ?
2015-12-15 10:30:01.187 DEBUG [Thread-2]: last date time is: null

2015-12-15 10:30:01.285 DEBUG [Thread-2]: Executing identity-insert immediately
2015-12-15 10:30:01.314 DEBUG [Thread-2]: 
    insert 
    into
        SMARTPARK.illuminazione
        (date_time, id_luce, isLit, last_date_time) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        SMARTPARK.illuminazione
        (date_time, id_luce, isLit, last_date_time) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Obviously if I run the same query in SQL, it works...

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not pass `idLuce` into the query. Try this

```
int idLuce = Integer.parseInt(msg);
session.beginTransaction();
selectQuery = "SELECT dateTime from Illuminazione i where i.idLuce = :idLuce ORDER BY i.dateTime ASC";
theQuery =  session.createQuery(selectQuery).setParameter("idLuce", idLuce).setMaxResults(1);
lastDate = (Date) theQuery.uniqueResult();
```

Or, move the `illuminazione.setIdLuce(idLuce);` line before executing the query.

Comment: you are right, i solved it using setParameter and not setProperties, even If i don't know why... thanks

Comment: `setProperties()` uses bean's properties to match them to query parameters. In the time of query execution, `illuminazione.idLuce` is null, which is why the query doesn't return any results. If you moved `illuminazione.setIdLuce(idLuce);` before executing the query, your old code would work.